# How can I create a view that splits data from one record in the source table into up to three records in the view?

Tags: sql

I am attempting to create a view in SQL Server 2000 that splits data into individual records from a source table.  Source table looks like this:

ShipID, AirlineID, Airport1, Airport2, AirlineID2, Airport3, Airport4, AirlineID3, Airport5, Airport6

My view needs to look like this:

ShipID, Airline, Origin, Destination

So my view needs to split each source record into up to three records in the view

Anyone know how best to do this?

Comment: Where do you get origin and destination from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should set you to your way. Mind added column Transfer. It is here to allow you to sort your flights by timeline.

```
select ShipID, 1 Transfer, AirlineID, Airport1 Origin, Airport2 Destination
  from mySourceTable
 where Airport1 is not null
union all
select ShipID, 2, AirlineID2, Airport3, Airport4 
  from mySourceTable
 where Airport3 is not null
union all
select ShipID, 3, AirlineID3, Airport5, Airport6 
  from mySourceTable
 where Airport5 is not null
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks, these two posts have helped a great deal!  I will test it out and repost if I have more trouble with it

Answer (score 0):

in general you do a few queries with a union between them, e.g., if airport 2 was always destination

```
SELECT shipid, airlineid, airport1, 'ORIGIN' FROM flight
UNION
SELECT shipid, airlineid, airport2, 'DESTINATION' FROM flight
```

That would get two records for each row in a table named flight.  However, you have to give more information on what is in the various columns and what rows you want out, in particular, if they're filled with blank space or NULL if not used.  And say what product you are using (MySql, Sql Server, Oracle, Access, Postgres, sticks and napkins, etc.)  Try reading some other posts tagged "SQL" to see what people include by way of data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Levin.  I am using SQL Server 2000 and shipid and airline will contain integers.  shipid, airlineid(the first one), airport1 and airport2 will not be null, all the others can be null and the view should have no row for them if that is the case